# Modify only the LSB of a memory cell

Tags: machine-instruction

Is it possible to write a sequence of instructions that will place a 1 in the least significant  bit of the memory cell at address B3 without disturbing the other bits in the memory cell?

The machine instructions I am referring to is the STOP, ADD, SWITCH, STOP, LOAD,  ROTATE etc.

Answer (score 0):

Clarification: this question [was originally tagged C#](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5063986/revisions); since it wasn't the OP that re-tagged it, I'll leave this here until the OP's intentions are clearer.

C# is a high-level programming language, which compiles down to IL, not machine code. As such: no, there is absolutely no supported mechanism for performing specific machine code operations (and even if there were, it couldn't possibly port between langauges).

You can do *high level* bit operations, using the operators on the integer-based types; and if you *really* want you can write IL, either building it manually (ilasm), or at runtime via `DynamicMethod` / `ILGenerator` - but these still only deal with CIL opcodes, not machine codes.

Answer (score 0):

I think ORing it with 1 will do the job ain't it:
algo:

byte= [data at 0xB3]
byte = byte | 0x01

this works fine with me in developing for 8051 MCUs.

Comment: So using the basic machine langauge (i.e. LOAD, ADD, STORE, SWITCH, HALT) etc, to write this procedure using the basic machine language. Can you help with this. i.e.